# Setting attribute equal to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes

So I have an inventory application API. Under a specific circumstance I need to raise the unit_price of my inventory by $10. I have named the circumstance I have set my condition to either be zero or 10 and that variable is saved in the attribute y factor. For testing purposes I have just set the yfactor for now to 10.

```
    def price 
      Inventory.unit_price= Inventory.unit_price + yfactor.to_f
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json{render}
      end
    end
```

I get undefined method (unit_price) error.

Using rails 4.

Comment: Inventory is (or should be) the name of your class.  You need to update the unit_price attribute for a class instance or set of class instances, not for the class itself.  Separately, you should be careful about maintaining currency as a floating point value due to issues with rounding.  Generally it is better to use a type like decimal.

Comment: I am confused since this looks like it should be an instance method of a model but then to are calling controller methods in it. Can you confirm where the method exists? BTW what I believe you are looking for is `def price; self.unit_price += yfactor.to_i; end` Since `yfactor` can be `0`, `10` or I assume `nil` converting it to a `float` has no real benefit.